# Trying to use java sdk and return Json and having issue with gson code

Tags: splunk

I am making a call to splunk and then I am trying to use the ResultsReaderJson class to get my results.

```
InputStream results = jobSavedSearch.getResults();
ResultsReaderJson resultsReader = new ResultsReaderJson(results);
```

And I keep getting this error.

```
com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 6
```

I have no access to the JsonReader from this class.  Does anybody have any ideas of what I can do to get around this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have not asked for the results stream to return you JSON. The default is XML. To fix this you could use:

```
Args outputArgs = new Args();
outputArgs.put("output_mode","json");
InputStream results = jobSavedSearch.getResults(outputArgs);
```

Answer (score 1):

In Splunk 1.3.0 API you can do:

```
  JobExportArgs jobargs = new JobExportArgs();
  jobargs.setOutputMode(JobExportArgs.OutputMode.JSON);
  InputStream exportSearch = jobSavedSearch.getResults(jobargs);
  MultiResultsReaderJson multiResultsReader = new MultiResultsReaderJson(exportSearch);
```